# Finding the limit of $\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{\arctan x}-\frac{1}{x}\right)$ when $x\to 0$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to find $$\lim _{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{\arctan x}-\frac{1}{x}\right)$$?

I tried doing it by L'Hospital, but I had to do it five times! Is there an easier way around this?

Comment: Hint: use Taylor expansion

Comment: Second hint: please use \frac{numerator}{denominator} for you fractions! Example: \frac{1}{x} produces $\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @the_candyman or use { numerator \over denominator}. I find this syntax more intuitive.

Comment: @addy2012 That's not proper $\LaTeX$. Some would burn you at the stake for this :)

Comment: @ClementC. i think it's not a problem to use it as long as it does not break the layout. which in most cases it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taylor expansions: much faster, *if you know the reference ones*. Here, we need the following two:
$$\begin{align}
\arctan x  &= x - \frac{x^3}{3} + o(x^3) \\
\frac{1}{1+x} &= 1-x + o(x)
\end{align}$$
(when $x\to 0$). *Note that, as a rule of thumb, we take the first one up to the order $3$ as we want to go "further than the first order $x$": since when we'll subtract $\frac{1}{x}$, this will basically "remove the first term of the expansion." We could have gone to higher orders, but that's not necessary: as long as we go far enough, the less expansion the less painful the computations will be.*

This leads to 
$$
\frac{1}{\arctan x} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{x^2}{3} + o(x^2)}- 1\right)
= \frac{1}{x}\left(1 + \frac{x^2}{3} + o(x^2)- 1\right)
 = \frac{x}{3} + o(x)
$$
so
$$
\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{\arctan x} - \frac{1}{x} \right)
= \frac{1}{3} + o(1) \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} \frac{1}{3}.
$$

Comment: For a list of some of the "reference ones" see e.g. [this](http://math.arizona.edu/~calc/SeriesTable.pdf) or [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions).